# Dates without time in ASP.NET Web API's JSON output

Tags: json, datetime, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Is there a simple way to configure JSON.NET so that **some** `DateTime` fields will be formatted without time and other `DateTime` fields will still be formatted with time?

Example:

```
{ firstName: 'John', lastName : 'Doe', birthday: '1965-09-23' }
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you need this to only affect a particular field, create a converter type first:

```
public class OnlyDateConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public OnlyDateConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}
```

and then add this attribute to whatever fields/properties you want this for:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(OnlyDateConverter))]
```

Comment: Nice.  I was just getting to write the same thing, but extending `DateTimeConverterBase`.  This is much cleaner!

Comment: Apparently you should use `/` instead of dashes for the benefit of certain old browsers : http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html

Comment: Should you make the property as a DateTime or as a string?

Comment: You can also use predefined `Microsoft.Rest.Serialization.DateJsonConverter` type from `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime` package (it is installed together with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package)

Comment: Great solution, searched a lot to try to find.  Thanks

Comment: @whyleee how would you use that one instead?

Comment: This did not work for me, I am still getting the time sent even if I decorate a model's property with this attribute.

Comment: As @JamesL. said this might not work because IsoDateTimeConverter is part of NewtonSoft.Json, but if you have a core-project it uses System.Text.Json as default when serializing, hence the attribute does not take effect.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this line to configure your Web API:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
    new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" });
```

Comment: That would have effect globally, not just on "some" fields, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Yousesef's answer with the `OnlyDateConverter` is best.  But here is one alternative:

```
private DateTime _birthday;
public string Birthday
{
    get { return _birthday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
    set {
          _birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
}
```

**Advantage** - You don't need to bind the Newtonsoft.Json library to your classes.

**Disadvantage** - The property is now exposed as a string anywhere you use it, which can cause it's own set of problems.

Comment: I've considered that approach, but it may not be the best when computations could be involved between dates. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Youssef works when using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize a single field in the model. But by default core uses System.Text.Json to serialize objects. The same thing can be achieved in core without Newtonsoft like so:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

internal class JsonOnlyDateConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString()!, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);            
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));            
    }
}
```

And use it in your model:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

...

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonOnlyDateConverter))]
public DateTime MyDateField { get; set; }
```