# Putting a "z" at the end if it is "datetime" and not "date" (JsonSerializerSettings)

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net

Facts:

1. In SQL Server there is the column type `datetime` and `date`
2. Using EF, both `datetime` and `date` are mapped to C#'s `DateTime`
3. In my `datetime` columns I'm always storing the UTC date.
4. In my current database there are no `date` columns, but I need to use it in a new table I'm going to have
5. My typical data flow is: `SQL Server --> C# (server side) --> JSON (client side)`

I've set my JSON Serializer to always return `DateTime` variables to the client with the format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ`, which is a good format for JavaScript. The Z at the end ("zulu") declares that it is in UTC timezone and so my client app knows that it needs to fix the timezone at display. Until now, everything needed to be timezone-fixed at display (because everything was UTC)

Because I want to start using the SQL Server type `date`, that `Z` at the end will be bothering in those `date` cases (but still needed in those `datetime` cases). As everything in my serverside is `DateTime`, I'm not sure how to make the JSON Serializer know which kind of `DateTime` is he looking at...

My question is... is it possible for the `JsonSerializerSettings` to know if he's converting a `DateTime` that came from a `date` or a `datetime`? If not, what's a good approach to solve this?

This is my Serializer:

```
public class JsonNetResult : ActionResult
{
    public Encoding ContentEncoding { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings { get; set; }
    public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }

    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        var isoDateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
        isoDateTimeConverter.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";

        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(isoDateTimeConverter);
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
          ...
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
return new JsonNetResult()
{
    Data = new
    {
        persons = dbContext.Persons.Select(e => new 
        {
             name = e.Name,
             someDate1 = e.SomeDate1, // datetime
             someDate2 = e.SomeDate2  // date
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you apply Json.NET attributes to your model?  You could apply a different subclass of `IsoDateTimeConverter` to `date` properties

Comment: Didn't thought of that, can you put an example?

Comment: Found an example `OnlyDateConverter` from [Dates without time in ASP.NET Web API's JSON output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16320762/3744182).

Comment: I will try it and post back the result. Looks promising @dbc

Comment: The attribute solution wouldn't work for me because of how I serialize directly from projections: `(e => new { someDate1 = e.SomeDate1, someDate2 = e.SomeDate2 })` ...as you can see I'm not serializing my `Person` object. I'm serializing the projection itself (a `dynamic` object)