# set custom format for datetime in the json response of c# odata web service

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, odata, datetime-format

I cerated odata webservice in C#
the JSON response return datetime field formatted like :

```
"updated": "2017-01-25T01:40:04",
```

how can I format it like "2017-01-25 01:40" ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Newtonsoft.Json and that you want the format to be global (apply the format to every date)

Put this in the `Application_Start` method:

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
     new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" });
```

More info in [this possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320762/dates-without-time-in-asp-net-web-apis-json-output)

Comment: does not work, maybe because the type edm.datetime does not match with IsoDateTime. I tried also using jsonConverter as attribute ... nothing

Comment: Then please add some details about your data types to your question. I assumed you are using System.DateTime.