# Format date and Filter by range

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

Hello I am trying to format a date

- that is in a csv in the format `dd / mm / yyyy`
- and would need to put it for `ddmmyyyy` in a json

  - filtered by a range, example from `01012019` until `31012019`

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

#### Serialization

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("../database.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

        var records = csv.GetRecords<Tabela>().ToList();
        // JSON writing
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records);
        File.WriteAllText("../database.json", json);

        System.Console.WriteLine(records);
    }
}
```

#### Model

```cs
class Tabela
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public String media { get; set; }
    public String client_id { get; set; }
    public String client_name { get; set; }
    public String campaign_id { get; set; }

    public String campaign_name { get; set; }

    public int clicks { get; set; }
    public int impressions { get; set; }
    public Double investment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The de-facto standard for JSON dates is the ISO8601 format, ie `YYYY-MM-DD`. There's no justification for using custom, localized formats that would require every client to adopt to them

Comment: In any case, JSON.NET allows you to customize how dates are serialized. There are several SO questions about this, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320762/dates-without-time-in-asp-net-web-apis-json-output)

Comment: `filtered by a range example 01012019 until 31012019` that string format *doesn't* allow filtering by ranges. Strings are compared using lexicographical ordering and `01012019` always comes before `02011970`, because the date elements are in reverse order. The ISO8601 format allows sorting and filtering because the elements are in the correct order

Answer (score 1):

This should be work:

```
        var validFrom = DateTime.TryParseExact("01012019", "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime from);
        var validTo = DateTime.TryParseExact("31012019", "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime to);

        if (validFrom && validTo)
        {

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Tabela>()
                .Where(x => x.date >= from && x.date <= to)
                .Select(x => new {
                    date = $"{x.date:ddMMyyyy}",
                    // ...
                    // the rest of the properties
                    // or selected
                })
                .ToList();
        }
```

example of how are the dates writen into json file:

```
File.WriteAllText("../../../dates.json", $"{{\n\t\"date\": \"{DateTime.Now:ddMMyyyy}\"\n}}");
```

[image]

Comment: Don't show the data in the json. Show the string "x.date"ddMMyyyy" after select

Comment: have you may be a null value instead of date